# Return a Mat object from jni to java

Tags: java, opencv, java-native-interface

Could somebody help me to return with an object array from native c to java?
I made its large part, only I need to set the Mat field.

The `getFaces()` function should return with a `Face[]` array.
The Face oject contains `opencv.core.Rect`, `opencv.core.Mat`, `int`, `int`, `int fields`

```
JNIEXPORT jobjectArray JNICALL Java_com_faceprocessing_PersonDetector_nativeGetFaces (JNIEnv * jenv, jclass) {

if (faceContainer.size()==0) return NULL;

jclass faceClass = jenv->FindClass("com/faceprocessing/Face");

jmethodID faceCtorID = jenv->GetMethodID(faceClass, "<init>", "()V");
jfieldID facePosID = jenv->GetFieldID(faceClass, "Position", "Lorg/opencv/core/Rect;");
jfieldID faceIDID = jenv->GetFieldID(faceClass, "PredictedID", "I");
jfieldID faceGenderID = jenv->GetFieldID(faceClass, "PredictedGender", "I");
jfieldID faceAgeID = jenv->GetFieldID(faceClass, "PredictedAge", "I");

jclass rectClass = jenv->FindClass("org/opencv/core/Rect");
jmethodID rectCtorID = jenv->GetMethodID(rectClass, "<init>", "(IIII)V");

jclass matClass = jenv->FindClass("org/opencv/core/Mat");


int correctCount = 0;
for (int i=0; i<faceContainer.size(); i++) {
    Face* pFace = faceContainer.at(i);
    if (!pFace->isError) correctCount++;
}

jobjectArray jFaceArray = jenv->NewObjectArray(correctCount, faceClass, NULL);

int j=0;
for (int i=0; i<faceContainer.size(); i++) {

    Face* pFace = faceContainer.at(i);
    if (pFace->isError) continue;
    jobject jFace = jenv->NewObject(faceClass, faceCtorID);
    jobject jRect = jenv->NewObject(rectClass, rectCtorID, pFace->facePosition->x, pFace->facePosition->y, pFace->facePosition->width, pFace->facePosition->height);
    jenv->SetObjectField(jFace, facePosID, jRect);
    jenv->SetIntField(jFace, faceIDID, pFace->predictedID);
    jenv->SetIntField(jFace, faceGenderID ,pFace->predictedGender);
    jenv->SetIntField(jFace, faceAgeID, pFace->predictedAge);
    jenv->SetObjectArrayElement(jFaceArray,j,jFace);
    j++;
}

return jFaceArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would not return `cv::Mat` array. I would return a single `cv::Mat` each time and create the array in Java side by calling the function as many times as needed.

So basicly, I would have a function for getting the size of the array. And another function to get the face image from the face container.

If you don't know how to return `cv::Mat` let me know.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have the same question, why returning an array of cv::Mat is not good?